# faster way for calling audio element to play in html5

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I'm trying to use audio elemnt in HTML5 mobile game.
I have some problems with sound effects,so I clone the audio elemnt many times in the start of the game like that :

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var container = document.getElementById("audioDiv");
            var clone = document.getElementById('multiaudio0').cloneNode(true);
            clone.setAttribute('id',"multiaudio" + i);
            container.appendChild (clone);
        };
```

Then when I need to use it "in collision" ,I call it as NEXT :

```
document.getElementById('audioDiv').getElementsByTagName("audio")[score%10].play();
```

The problem that it is very slow and slow down the animation on canvas while calling the element and play it !!!!
Some times also it do NOT work !!!

Any idea about sound for mobile games in HTML5 (without flash),or a best practice for fast calling for the element rather than      `document.getElementById` ???

Comment: You can try using the `Audio` class instead of using DOM. So, you'll need to maintain an `Audio` object for each sound you use, and can simply play the sound with `audioObject.play()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend pre-defining an array that contains the pointers to the various audio elements before you call one (rather than repeat the `document.getElementById('audioDiv').getElementsByTagName("audio")` lookup multiple times
Also make sure you have pre-loaded the audio samples so they are cached and you're not waiting on network resources the first time you need them

If you are working on an HTML5 based game I'd suggest you have a look at the EaselJS framework, especially the SoundJS pieces... http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS